# How am I able to run an .mm file on OS X?

Tags: c, macos, gcc, terminal, opencl

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/OpenCL_NBody_Simulation_Example/Introduction/Intro.html

I'm trying to get into OpenCL and tried to download this test code- the main method was in a file called "main.mm", but I am lost on how to actually run it. Any ideas?

Comment: A .mm file contains Objective-C++, and must be compiled and linked before you can run it.  You can do this either in the XCode IDE or using clang++ on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the sample code from the "Download Sample Code" button and then you will need to compile it with xCode. After that, you will be able to run it.

Comment: How exactly do I compile it in XCode? Do I need to make a project, add all the files to it and build from there?

Comment: @Skorpius, yep. You will need to add all the files in the download to a new project. You may have to run through some Xcode tutorials to learn how to use Xcode, it is not trivial. But, yeah, you want to create a project, add the files and compile.

Comment: Well I tried to build as a Cocoa application and it failed for whatever reason...